# Can't migrate logical volume to newly added physical volumes

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I had a partition of 91GB added in a logical volume filled to 61GB. Now I got an external hard drive and added a couple of partitions 43GB and 26GB each to the logical volume.

I now want to move the data to these new pvs and repartition the original 91GB partition. I started out with `pvmove -v /dev/sdxx` but it says Insufficient free space. Not enough extents. I am confused. My vgdisplay shows me as 91.23GB allocated. Why?

Here's the partition table of my hard disk:

```
/dev/sda5   91G
/dev/sda1   58G
```

I have my /home as a logical volume with /dev/sda5 as physical volume.

I now have an external hard drive partition table as follows:

```
/dev/sdb1    43G
/dev/sdb2    26G
/dev/sdb3    80G
```

`df -h /home` gives:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/home-home--lvm
                      91G   61G  343M  100% /home
```

I want to remove /dev/sda5 from /home and repartition it. I have /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 free, so I want to add them to the lv home. How do I get this done?

Comment: can you please reformat your question and include a tab formatted list of your HDDs/LVMs information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was initially naive enough to just add /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2. And try pvmove on /dev/sda5.

Here are the steps that solved the problem:

- Boot into maintenance mode, umount the /home
- resize2fs to within the size the new
  partitions can hold. (here 68G).*
- lvresize the logical volume.
- Use pvmove /dev/sda1*
- Now pvremove /dev/sda1
- Format it as you please

  - -- Both highly time consuming operations. 
    You can skip the pvmove and resize the partition following the instructions here. http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions
    But then it involves tampering with the partition table, while the data is not backed up. So you better be aware of the risk involved.